# Guarde el diseño del formulario para despues volver a editarlo, y una vez guardado se me ceero automaticamente y me aparecio uno nuevo sin modficacion

Tags: c#, api, windows-forms, .net, formularios

Tengo un problema, cree un formulario desde la parte del diseño y mientras el codigo se iba actualizando solo, quize guardarlo y desaparecio el formulario, solo me quedo el codigo, y como estoy aprendiendo necesito tenerlo para seguir editandolo, a alguien le paso? que puedo hacer?

Comment: y el codigo?, y el error?, se necesitan antecedentes, evidencia para ayudar a solucionar un problema.

Comment: Intenta Ctrl - Z

Comment: En donde me aparecia el formulario, Form1.Designer.cs, ahora me aparece solo el codigo, no se como llamar al formulario para editarlo, si puedo depurarlo y aparece como esta actualmente el formulario, pero no el proyecto para poder editarlo, ya no me aparece el proyecto para agregarle textbox, groupbox, etc

Comment: aprieta F7 o Shift F7

Comment: SOLUCIONADO, muchas gracias!

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Luego editar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Click derecho en el codigo -> ver diseñador.
O en el explorador de soluciones clic derecho en el 'Form1.cs' por ejemplo y ver diseñador.